# Travel to Sweden after work permit is approved

Tags: visas, paperwork, sweden, emergencies

I am from Asia and I have applied for work permit for Sweden which is approved by Swedish agency. Last week I gave biometrics for UT card and now I am waiting for UT card to be dispatched to me. But mean while I need to travel for some very urgent business meeting. So question is - is there any temp visa I can get while wait for my UT card to arrive. I know UT card only takes few days to arrive but I need to travel ASAP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What passport do you hold/what country are you a citizen of?

Answer (score 1):

If you would not require a visa to visit the Schengen Area, then you can fly to Sweden and enter on your passport. In this case, notify *Migrationsverket* that you've already arrived, so you can collect the residence permit in Sweden.

If you require a visa, however, you're not getting in without your permit, nor will airport check-in staff let you on a plane to Sweden.